# JAR file that reads .cfg file and produces a text file

Tags: java, jar, nullpointerexception, filereader, filewriter

I developed a small program that takes as input some configuration parameters from a `.cfg` file and produces an output `.txt` file based on the values taken from the `.cfg` file.

While the program runs perfectly in eclipse, I receive a NullPointerException error when I create a JAR file of this program and try to run it. From my understanding I have to make the JAR access its internal files or try to receive the needed information (in this case the `.cfg` file) externally, e.g. create a resource folder next to the JAR file.

I have searched many related questions asked here but I got even more confused whether there is an optimal way to produce a JAR file that can access input files and produces output files. Should I modify my code to achieve this or there is another way?

For the record, I use `FileReader` and `FileWriter` to access and produce the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `.cfg` file is outside of the JAR file, it should work just as in Eclipse.

If you want to access it from inside of the JAR archive, then you should use a class loader to load it, instead of `FileReader`...

Comment: For some reason in macOS I was getting a NullPointerException error even when the `.cfg` file was outside the JAR. I switched to Windows and the JAR works fine, so I guess my unfamiliarity with the other OS was the problem.